# How detail with cjk character correctly for webpage?

Tags: html, utf-8, wget, cjk

I am not able to see the cjk characters correctly. It seems that it is mistaken as in ISO-8859 encode. I think the UTF-8 encode is the appropriate one. Does anybody know how to fix the problem.

```
$ wget http://yjs.cd120.com/daoshi.html 
$ grep 'selectid="99"' daoshi.html 
Binary file daoshi.html matches
$ file daoshi.html 
daoshi.html: HTML document text, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to determine what is the actual encoding of the file obtained through `wget` (or `curl` for that matter).

Issuing the command:

```
grep 'Content-Type' daoshi.html
```

will display:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

where `charset=gb2312` means that the html file is encoded in *Simplified Chinese (GB 2312)*.

Then, you can use the `iconv` command to convert the file to a new UTF-8 version:

```
iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 daoshi.html >daoshi-utf8.html
```

Finally, depending on your needs, you may want to adjust the `meta` tag contents at the beginning of the file to match the new encoding, using `sed` for instance:

```
sed s/charset=gb2312/charset=utf-8/ daoshi-utf8.html >daoshi-utf8-final.html
```

Comment: I got this error. Do you know what is wrong? Thanks. ```$ wget -qO- http://yjs.cd120.com/daoshi-2.html| iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8  > /dev/null

iconv: (stdin):430:173: cannot convert
```

Comment: `wget -qO- http://yjs.cd120.com/daoshi.html| iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 > /dev/null` works fine, so the problem is in the file `daoshi-2.html`: it contains a character at position 430:173 that `iconv` cannot convert... You may try to download the file without converting it, then have some hex dump of that line to spot the "culprit"... You can also add the `-c` option to the `iconv` command to  silently discard characters that cannot be converted, instead of leading to a conversion error: `wget -qO- http://yjs.cd120.com/daoshi-2.html| iconv -c -f gb2312 -t utf-8 > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

**Summary:**

Step 1: Save the data as UTF-8

Step 2: Declare the encoding in your page

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Step 3: Ensure that your server does the right thing